# How to clear cache in Controller in Symfony3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, php-7.1, symfony-3.4

after migration Symfony from 3.3 to 3.4, my function not working (it works before). I have to clear cache in controller, and when I execute command below, function returns error.

```
exec(sprintf(
  "php %s/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod",
  $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')
));
```

It returns something like that:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/[...]/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcrshql/getTwig_ExceptionListenerService.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /[...]/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcrshql/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 764 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/[...]/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcrshql/getSwiftmailer_EmailSender_ListenerService.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /[...]/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcrshql/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 764
```

In addition I can tell You, that in dev environment it works properly. Also when project run localy and simulate prod env (in address bar I type app.php after localhost:8000). I haven't other server to check if problem still occured

Comment: Are you sure that this is the cache that you want to clear? What are you doing that requires clearing **this** cache?

Comment: Im sure, of course. I allow to change translations files by admin panel. I store global settings in yml files, and also user can change it by admin panel

Comment: Use database for that like every sane person would. You don't want to cause downtime just because of changed translation.

Comment: In previous Symfony version it works. Application is online, it is no time to rebuild all application :(

Comment: If by "previous version" you mean Symfony2, then sure, you're most likely doing wrong right now... Symfony3 have a built-in translation... Enable it...  
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation.html. As for your cache problem, it's a permission issue. Check how to set proper permission for a web server. ;)

Comment: @Preciel previous version means Symfony3.3. Application ran about a month and than I made upgrade to 3.4. After that it was broken. Im using Symfony translations + jms/i18n-routing-bundle, but user defines the meaning of single words. So even if whole project has 777 permissions, the problem still occured

Comment: Symfony 3.3 and 3.4 aren't compatible (don't know why)... If you used composer to upgrade, then return to 3.3. I had the same issue with one of my projet, going from 3.3 to 3.4 broke everything. If you really want to use 3.4, then create a new symfony project, and move all your entities, view, forms, etc. that should do the trick... ;)

Comment: @Preciel - While I don't know the answer to this particular issue to say that 3.4 is not compatible with 3.3 is just plain silly.  Lots of things can go wrong when you bump up a version.

Comment: @preciel i've done this with composer [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html) and it seems that everything its ok (except this cache...)

Comment: @jdoe Yeah, I did as well, and like you I had an error and couldn't clear cache. I'm not suited to figure out the problem, thus I suggest that you turn back to 3.3 (hopping you did back up the composer.json file). Else you might want to download a 3.4 and copy/paste all the files in the vendor folder. If it's not a permissions problem, then it can only come from Symfony itself I think.

Comment: @jdoe just in case, did you try to manually delete the content of `/var/cache` in your Symfony project? If it solve you problem, then the issue really is permissions related.

Comment: @Preciel - I know this is off topic but I have moved a number of apps from 3.x to 3.4 by editing composer.json.  And I just did a fresh install of 3.3 and moved it to 3.4 with no problem.  I understand there can be difficulties and I often end up in composer hell myself and I would never try to jump a major version but the minor version stuff pretty much works out of the box at least.

Answer (score 8):

I'm calling an already implemented Symfony's command that clear or warmup cache (tested on Symfony 4).

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class CommandController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/command/cache/clear", name="command_cache_clear")
     */
    public function command_cache_clear(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        return $this->do_command($kernel, 'cache:clear');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/command/cache/warmup", name="command_cache_warmup")
     */
    public function command_cache_warmup(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        return $this->do_command($kernel, 'cache:warmup');
    }

    private function do_command($kernel, $command)
    {
        $env = $kernel->getEnvironment();
        
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        
        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => $command,
            '--env' => $env
        ));
        
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        
        $content = $output->fetch();
        
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a valid permissions to the var/ directory to access to cache files:

```
chmod ... var/ -R
```

The user used when accessing from web is www-data

Comment: that was the first thing I did when I detected the error

Comment: So you should verify that kernel.project_dir contain a valid path to the project

Comment: You can replace $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') by `__DIR__ . '/../../..'`

Comment: it was next try. I also check command `rm -rf ~/[...]/var/cache` and I tried deleting via 'Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem' method remove